# Symfony 2.1 - FPNTagBundle with annotated Tag entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have installed [FPNTagBundle](https://github.com/FabienPennequin/FPNTagBundle) via composer. I have successfully added tags to my articles, but when I add DoctrineExtensions' `TagRepository` as the repositoryClass with

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="DoctrineExtensions\Taggable\Entity\TagRepository")
 * @ORM\Table
 */
class Tag extends FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tag
```

and try to use TagRepository's method `getResourceIdsForTag('post', 'tagname')`, it fails. I've checked the repository class with

```
$tagRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('GergelyPolonkaiFrontBundle:Tag');
echo get_class($tagRepo);
```

and it's not `TagRepository`, but `Doctrine\ORM\Entity\Repository`. I don't have any other error message regarding the repositoryClass thing, even if I specify an invalid classname.

Have I found a bug, or do I miss something somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was hitting a bug. After merging some pull requests by Fabien Pennequin 16 days ago, it now seems working as expected.